# Show booleans in Active Admin as 'Yes' and 'No'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, activeadmin

How can I make active admin to show "Yes" and "No" instead of "true" and "false".

I tried to change in english locale but that doesn't work.
I'm thinking of monkeypatching boolean classes, but this seems quite ugly.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here, this works, it gives you a tick and cross, but appears to be easy to modify.

https://gist.github.com/2574969

You'll need to restart your rails server for this to work, as it modifies the active_admin.rb initialiser.

Of course it creates a class, which is what you want to avoid, but in the absence of anything else, this does work.

Answer (score 55):

You might like to do something like this:

```
index do
  id_column
  column(:published) do |story| 
    story.published? ? status_tag( "yes", :ok ) : status_tag( "no" )
  end
end
```

This will wrap the words "yes" and "no" in status tags which look rather good.

Comment: Thanks Scott, they look nice don't they. You can specify the colour using :red, :green or :grey too.

Comment: modify it to t("yes") and i18n is OK, too :)

Comment: @HugoLogmans even if I try to use `t('yes')` and also `I18n.translate('yes')` I keep getting `translation missing`... I restarted the server and everything... Any idea?

Comment: This is a new question, post it as a new question. But first google it.

Comment: For reference the solution to the I18n issue can be found here: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2011
In short, make sure to wrap the **keys** in the yml file with double quotes, "yes" and "no".

Answer (score 16):

Try to use condition directly in active admin as below

```
column :column_name do|object|
    object.column_name? ? 'Yes' : 'No'
end
```

Comment: Don't know why this hasn't been upvoted yet, seems like the simplest solution. Following your example I did: `column :us_citizen, Proc.new {|obj| obj.us_citizen? ? 'Yes' : 'No'}`

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple,

Suppose your Boolean field name is active,

create a method named status like

```
def status
  self.active ? "Yes" : "No"
end
```

Use the **status** as a normal field in active admin show or index.

Answer (score 2):

As Ahmad said you want to avoid creating classes just for that.

So there's another solution:

In your active_admin.en.yml locale (or whatever) just add those two lines:

```
en:
  "true": Yes
  "false": No
```

Then in your app/admin/my_model.rb file for instance to display Yes/No on index page, just do this:

```
column :published do |post|
      t(post.published.to_s)
end
```

So you just have to turn to string your boolean and to use the "t" function (i18n translation) so Rails will search in your locales file the right translation and replace 'true/false' by 'Yes/No'.

I think it's a better solution, you follow the "Rails Spirit" and it becomes easier to have an active_admin panel in different languages.

The drawback (because there's allways one) it's that you'll need to use the "t" function each time you want to replace booleans by Yes/No...

It'd be great to make a pull request to the active_admin gem offering the possibility to replace booleans just by changing the yml file like I did.

But... untill it's done, my solution works fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this can also go, without any more monkey patching.

For Rails 5.

```
column :signed_up?, sortable: 'signed_up' do |interest|
  ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean::FALSE_VALUES.exclude?(interest.signed_up)
end
```

For Rails 4.

```
column :signed_up?, sortable: 'signed_up' do |interest|
  ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean::TRUE_VALUES.include?(interest.signed_up)
end

column :signed_up?, sortable: 'signed_up' do |interest|
  ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean::FALSE_VALUES.exclude?(interest.signed_up)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If an extra dependency doesn't bother you, check out https://github.com/parabuzzle/humanize_boolean which automates the feature and supports i18n.